# Limiting results of Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I wanted to ask, how can I limit results of search. 
This is piece of code, responsible for quering.
I want to have only five autocomplete items.

Source:

```
 function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'person':request
            },

            url: 'PersonWatch/all',

            success: function(data) {
                response( $.map( data, function(item, i) {
                        return item.person
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
response($.map(data, function(item, i) {
             return i < 5 ? item.person : null
         })
        );
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but now i have no chance to count all results, 
I'm wondering, how transform code, to have 5 results and also have possibility to show number of all results in other place.

Comment: @user2610146 Try adding `$.ajaxSetup({
        context: elem
    });` before `.autocomplete()` , where `elem` is `input` element ; `this.data("responseLength", data.length);` or `this.data("responseLength", data.person.length);`  within `success` callback of `ajax` ; adding`response` `event` http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response  `response:function(event, ui) {console.log("response length:" + $(this).data("responseLength"), ui)}` http://jsfiddle.net/wr1wg5df/7/